# SSIS Package not visible after DTUTIL import

Tags: ssis, sql-server-2008-r2

I'm able to import package into integration services via DTUTIL  import, however when I access integration services I cannot find the package in question.

The command used is as follows:

```
DTUTIL /FILE C:\temp\<PackageFile>.dtsx /DestServer <servername> /copy SQL;<Packagename>/DestU <Username> /DestP <Password>
```

When I import the package.dtsx from the SQL management studio integration services, will successful import and render the package.

I'm not sure whether we need to include additional parameters to specify the root of the msdb (root).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resolved the issue, by specifying the path in quotes as shown below:

```
/COPY SQL;\<Package>
```

instead of

```
/COPY SQL; <Package>
```

That works

Comment: I'm confused, the syntax you posted in your question did not show a space between the `SQL;` and the package name. As I recall, the backslash is only allowed if deploying into subfolders.

Comment: I would agree, my understanding is that you don't need the backslash to deploy to root of the msdb; however it appears to work.  Thank you for all your assistance in this matter. I've got a feeling, I'll be talking to you a lot in relation to SSIS

Answer (score 1):

Your syntax for uploading a package to the root is correct. Try running a query to ensure the packages exist as you expect them-[SSIS Package Query](http://billfellows.blogspot.com/2011/08/ssis-package-query.html)

That should build out a result set showing all the packages you have in your `<servername>` instance. If those are showing, then it's a matter of fiddling with the Integration Services Service. Is there more than one instance on this box?

Comment: Yes, there is more than one instance on the box. But that was 2005 and the service has been disabled.